# React Style is Not Gone on Page Change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a Home.js component that NavLink takes me to. This file has `import 'home.scss';` The problem is that when I click on another NavLink to go to another page, the style from Home.js is not gone. Why does this happen and how can I load the home styles only on the home page?

Comment: CSS is not scoped for page. It will be injected in the head.

Comment: Is there any way I can remove the injection, or scope it in the page?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, But what is the use case? Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: On the home page, the navbar looks different than on other pages. I've got the default navbar styles that appear on every page in _header.scss while the variation of it on the homepage shows up in _home.scss page. Home and Header are different components.

Comment: have a parent class and style based on that. toggle that parent class

Comment: Looks like that's what I'll go for.